# How to make a Thrift client for multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thrift

I have a working Thrift client in the below snippet.

```
TTransport transport = new THttpClient(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/api/"));
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
TMultiplexedProtocol mp = new TMultiplexedProtocol(protocol, "UserService");
UserService.Client userServiceClient = new UserService.Client(mp);
System.out.println(userServiceClient.getUserById(100));
```

When running the client within multi-threaded environment

```
threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(userServiceClient.getUserById(someId));
    }
}
```

I got an exception: **out of sequence response**

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: getUserById failed: out of sequence response
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:76)
```

I guess the reason is that Thrift generated Client is not thread safe.
But if I want multi-clients to call the same method `getUserById()` simultaneously, how can I make it?

Comment: Probably a client (`new  THttpClient(..); ...`) per thread, is there a connection pool you can use? (I don't know thrift)

Comment: Yes there is a connection pool for THttpClient but it doesn't fix the issue. When I make a completely new client (i.e., userServiceClient_2 with mp_2, protocol_2 and transport_2) then it works. But I don't think it's a good approach to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thrift clients are not designed to be shared across threads. If you need multiple client threads, set up one Thrift client per thread.

> But if I want multi-clients to call the same method getUserById() simultaneously, how can I make it?

We don't know much about the context, so I have to guess a bit. If the issue is that there are a lot of such calls coming in at a time, a possible solution could be to group calls to save roundtrip time:

```
service wtf {
  list<string>  getUsersById( 1 : list<int> userIds)
}
```

That's just a short idea. Maybe you want to return `list<user_data_struct>` instead. For practical reasons I would also recommend to wrap the returned list into a struct, so the whole thing becomes extensible.

Comment: I want to make multiple threads to call not only the same method, but also multiple methods simultaneously. I see that I have to make a new client (with a new TTransport, TProtocol and TMultiplexedProtocol) for each thread.